# last occurrence of string in a line

Tags: sed, awk

I'm new to linux and am having difficulty achieving the following. I have a file with package names within on each line.

for example:

```
abc/123/new/package/abc/123/new/package
abc/124/new/package/abc/123/new/package
abc/125/new/package/abc/123/new/package
abc/126/new/package/abc/123/new/package
```

The package names are repeating. I only need the second half starting from the second abc in each line and onward and then output that to a file.

I have tried to read up on awk and sed, however, this seems a little bit advanced for my first day trying to learn this stuff. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide expected output from above desired script.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following sed command:

```
sed -E 's#^.*(abc/.*)$#\1#g' file
```

Comment: I noticed this works for linux, Would it be different in a unix system as the application i'm creating will be implemented on both systems and now i'm reading unix may use nawk vs awk :S?

Comment: I have tried this on Linux and Mac and it has worked so I believe it would work same on the any Unix system.

Answer (score 0):

Using sed to delete first 4 levels:

```
sed 's!^[^/]*/[^/]*/[^/]*/[^/]*!!' input_file
```

or using repeat pattern:

```
sed 's!^\([^/]*/\)\{4\}!/!' input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do:

```
sed -E 's,^.+(abc/),\1,'input_file
```

Comment: This is essentially identical to @anubhava's answer of 26 minutes ago. Is there something new in this answer?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do this.  If the text you want to keep always starts in the same column position (21), use:

```
cut -b 21- < input-file > output-file
```

If it is always the last occurrence of "abc..." that you want, try:

```
awk '{print FS $NF}' FS=abc input-file > output-file
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is my first post...I'm going to read up on awk and if I have any major issues i'll search this forum...Thanks again! Extremely useful resource this site is!